# How to validate complex JSON array in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, server-side, laravel-validation

I make a post request to the Laravel server from the Vue.js server. How I can validate complex array in request on the server-side.

Here is my request payload:

```json
{
    "insurance": [
        "Blue Cross Blue Shield",
        "United Behavioral Health",
        "Aetna Behavioral Health",
        "Tricare East","Medicare","Humana"
      ],
    "caqh": {
        "username":"myusername",
        "password":"my password"
     },
    "nppes": {
        "username":"new username",
        "password":"passowrd"
    }
}
```

I want to validate all the fields via `$request->validate([ 'username'=>'required' ])` How would I achieve this?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 4):

```
$request->validate([
    'insurance' => 'required',
    'insurance.caqh' => 'required',
    'insurance.nppes' => 'required',
    'insurance.caqh.username' => 'required',
    'insurance.nppes.username' => 'required',
    ])
```

Comment: The method is not working. I submitted  all the values but it is still returning errors

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more ? You can `dd($request->all())` and check the structure of data you are trying to validate and then compare it with validation rules